# Flutter SfCalendar customize "dot"

Tags: flutter, dart, syncfusion

Is it possible to Customize the "dot" (Picture) inside the SfCalendar widget? I want a Icon there instead of a simple colored dot. Or is there a other package where this is possible?
Code:

```
 body: SfCalendar(
      view: CalendarView.month,
      initialSelectedDate: DateTime.now(),
      initialDisplayDate: DateTime.now(),
      dataSource: events,

      controller: _controller,
      onSelectionChanged: selectionChanged,
      monthViewSettings: const MonthViewSettings(
        showAgenda: true,
      ),
      onTap: (details) {
        if (details.targetElement == CalendarElement.appointment || details.targetElement == CalendarElement.agenda) {
          final Meeting appointmentDetails = details.appointments![0];
          databaseReference.collection('CalendarAppointmentCollection').doc(appointmentDetails.id).delete();
          getDataFromFireStore().then((results) {
            setState(() {});
          });
        }
      },
    ));
```

Here the picture. [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your requirement by customizing the calendar month cell with an appointment count by using the "**monthCellBuilder**" property of the calendar.

Refer to the KB document at the following link to learn how to customize the month cell with an appointment count in the Flutter calendar: https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/12306/how-to-customize-the-month-cell-with-appointment-count-in-the-flutter-calendar.

To know more details about "monthCellBuilder" support from the calendar, please refer to the UG document at the following link: https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/calendar/builders#month-cell-builder